# Secondary Oracle Database creation

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to create a database (secondary) in Oracle (Linux based) using DBCA. But ended up with 'ORA-27125: unable to create shared memory segment'.  I already have a database (instance) and now trying to create one more.  Why am I getting this ORA-27125 error at 2% of progress? What wrong am I doing?

Comment: If the kernel parameter kernel.shmall is correct, then you have run out of memory on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Kernel parameter kernel.shmall is too small
[ora-27125](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/ora-27125-unable-to-create-shared-memory-segment-error-28-no-space-left-on-device/)